# How to map a child with a constructor that refer to the parent class in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB (with the csharp driver) on a project and I'm trying to figure out something. See the class structure below :

```
public class A
{
   public IEnumerable<B> Collection {get;}
   public A()
   {
      Collection = new List<B>();
   }
}

public class B
{
   private A _parent;
   public B(A parent)
   {
      _parent=parent;
   }
   public Parent A => _parent;
}
```

I'm trying to configure the mapping in Mongo so it will pass the current deserialized instance of A when it deserialize the child B. By default, the Parent property of B isn't serialized. Also, I need to create a mapper for class B because there's no default constructor but I can't figure out how to tell the mapper class to pass the instance of A as a constructor paramter of B. Any clues ?

Comment: I found another way to populate my model but if a MongoDB guru has an answer for my question, I'll by curious to see if it's possible (or not) and how.